# how to write a mysql function in codeigniter join() method

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I'm in big trouble in codeigniter.

I want to use FIND_IN_SET mysql function in codeigniter join() function. But problem is codeigniter consider FIND_IN_SET as a  field name.

Please check below code:

```
$this->db->select("gcpo.promotional_offer_id,gcpo.promotional_offer_name,gcpo.promotional_offer_code,gcpo.promotional_offer_type,gcpo.promotional_offer_discount,gcpo.promotional_offer_min_amount,gcpo.promotional_offer_uses_per_offer,gcpo.promotional_offer_start_date,gcpo.promotional_offer_end_date,name,gcpo.promotional_offer_is_active,gcpo.promotional_offer_added_date,count(gcopo.promotional_offer_code) as cntP");
    $this->db->from("promotional_offer gcpo");
    $this->db->join("customer_groups", "FIND_IN_SET(id,promotional_offer_customer_group) > 0");
    $this->db->join("order_promotional_offer gcopo", "gcopo.promotional_offer_code=gcpo.promotional_offer_code","left");
    $this->db->group_by('gcpo.promotional_offer_code');
    $this->db->limit($_GET['iDisplayLength'], $start);
    $this->db->order_by($sort_array[$_GET['iSortCol_0']], $_GET['sSortDir_0']);
    $query = $this->db->get();
```

In mysql query output which given by codeigniter:

```
SELECT `gcpo`.`promotional_offer_id`, `gcpo`.`promotional_offer_name`, `gcpo`.`promotional_offer_code`, `gcpo`.`promotional_offer_type`, `gcpo`.`promotional_offer_discount`, `gcpo`.`promotional_offer_min_amount`, `gcpo`.`promotional_offer_uses_per_offer`, `gcpo`.`promotional_offer_start_date`, `gcpo`.`promotional_offer_end_date`, `name`, `gcpo`.`promotional_offer_is_active`, `gcpo`.`promotional_offer_added_date`, count(gcopo.promotional_offer_code) as cntP FROM (`gc_promotional_offer` gcpo) JOIN `gc_customer_groups` ON `FIND_IN_SET`(`id,promotional_offer_customer_group)` > 0 LEFT JOIN `gc_order_promotional_offer` gcopo ON `gcopo`.`promotional_offer_code`=`gcpo`.`promotional_offer_code` GROUP BY `gcpo`.`promotional_offer_code` ORDER BY `gcpo`.`promotional_offer_added_date` desc LIMIT 10
```

now please find the find_in_set function in mysql query you will find like field name that consider by codeigniter .

Answer (score 2):

`FIND_IN_SET` is a restriction function, you want to use it with a `where`. First you need to join `customer_groups`, and then restrict results with a `where`.

Change `__PUT JOIN CONDITION HERE__` with your condition, and prefix `FIND_IN_SET` with correct table alias.

```
$this->db->select("gcpo.promotional_offer_id,gcpo.promotional_offer_name,gcpo.promotional_offer_code,gcpo.promotional_offer_type,gcpo.promotional_offer_discount,gcpo.promotional_offer_min_amount,gcpo.promotional_offer_uses_per_offer,gcpo.promotional_offer_start_date,gcpo.promotional_offer_end_date,name,gcpo.promotional_offer_is_active,gcpo.promotional_offer_added_date,count(gcopo.promotional_offer_code) as cntP");
$this->db->from("promotional_offer gcpo");
$this->db->join("order_promotional_offer gcopo", "gcopo.promotional_offer_code=gcpo.promotional_offer_code","left");
$this->db->join("customer_groups", "__PUT JOIN CONDITION HERE__");
$this->db->where("FIND_IN_SET(id,promotional_offer_customer_group) > 0");
$this->db->group_by('gcpo.promotional_offer_code');
$this->db->limit($_GET['iDisplayLength'], $start);
$this->db->order_by($sort_array[$_GET['iSortCol_0']], $_GET['sSortDir_0']);
$query = $this->db->get();
```

Comment: Hello Treast,

I'm already used FIND_IN_SET function in join but not interact with codeigniter but directly into mysql command prompt.
But when I'm using with codeigniter then its consider as a field. Please check mysql query in my quetions.

I have also tried with where conditions but its work fine but in other matter.

But thanks for your reply.
I'll try your code in my project. If this will work then I'll let you know

Thanks